# How to use trained Scikit Learn Python model in GoLang?

Tags: python, go, scikit-learn

I have trained a Scikit Learn model in Python environment which i need to use it for inference in GoLang. Could you please help me how can i export/save my model in python and then use it back in GoLang.

I found a solution for Neural Network model where i can save Tensorflow model in ONNX format and load it using Onnx-go in GoLang. But this is specific for Neural Network models. But I am unable to figure it out for scikit-learn models.

Answer (score 3):

Found out the following solutions.

**Solution1:**

We should be exporting the python model in PMML format and then import in GoLang using [GoScore](https://github.com/asafschers/goscore) Library

Here is a GoLang code snippet loading PMML file using GoScore

```
modelXml, err := ioutil.ReadFile("titanic_rf.pmml")
if (err != nil) {
  panic(err)    
}
var model goscore.RandomForest 
xml.Unmarshal([]byte(modelXml), &model)

features := map[string]interface{}{
  "Sex": "male",
  "Parch": 0,
  "Age": 30,
  "Fare": 9.6875,
  "Pclass": 2,
  "SibSp": 0,
  "Embarked": "Q",
}

score, _ := model.Score(features, "0") // scores 0.486
score, _ := model.Score(features, "1") // scores 0.514
score, _ := model.LabelScores(features) // map[0:243 1:257]
```

Found this solution referring to [this medium article](https://medium.com/@aschers/deploy-machine-learning-models-from-r-research-to-ruby-go-production-with-pmml-b41e79445d3d). (Although its R Model to GoLang, it still relevant)

**Solution2**:

[SkLearn-Porter](https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter) is library in python to port models into various languages. Unfortunately, It doesn't support all the models for Go at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop an REST json API service to expose your scikit-learn model and  communicate with go client.

Comment: Actually It's not allowed to do that as per the scope of my project. Training environment setup is configured for Python where i cant use GoLang at the moment. The Inference environment needs to be very fast and should also be in GoLang so as to be integratable with other part of codes. Although this situation may change in future by making Training setup compatible with GoLang, but that would take few more months atleast.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no choice to accomplish it in go. Using the REST API service is a common way to communicate between ML service and other components.